# MVC 5 - While trying to delete a row using linq, there is no error and the row is not deleted. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I've tried many different ways to delete some rows for the `IncidentDescriptions` DBContext, but I really cannot figure this one out.  In the debug window, there is an ID and a description that prints out that is being displayed from this line, so I know that there is a row being selected and that cannot be the issue:

```
foreach (var desc in DB.IncidentDescriptions.Where(d => d.AccidentHeaderId == supervisor.AccidentHeaderId)) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(desc.Id + " " + desc.Description);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = @"Id,AccidentHeaderId,DateLastModified,LastModifiedUsername,DateAccidentReported,EmployeeReported,ReportedInSameShift
,DateReportedOutsideShift,AccidentLocation,IncidentDate,IncidentTime,MedicalAttention,Clinic,ReturnToWork,DrugScreenPapers,DamageDesc,MissDollarEst,ActsContributed
,CorrectiveActions,DiscusedWithEmployee,WorkOrderComplete,Comments,AccidentNarrative,FirstName,LastName,DrugTested,FirstNameReportedTo,LastNameReportedTo
,DateInvestigationStarted,TimeInvestigationStarted,DeptManager, HospitalName,
BodyPartXREF, EmployeesInvolved, IncidentDescriptions, InjuryDescriptionXREF, UnsafeActXREF, WitnessesInvolved
")] AccidentSupervisorViewModel supervisor, List<string> SelectedUnsafeActs, int? SelectedLocation, List<string>DescriptionUser, List<string>DescriptionPosition)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (DB)
        {
            using (var contextTransaction = DB.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                foreach (var desc in DB.IncidentDescriptions.Where(d => d.AccidentHeaderId == supervisor.AccidentHeaderId)) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(desc.Id + " " + desc.Description);
                }
                DB.IncidentDescriptions.Remove(DB.IncidentDescriptions.FirstOrDefault(d => d.AccidentHeaderId == supervisor.AccidentHeaderId));
                DB.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    contextTransaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Incident"); 
    }
    return View(supervisor);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not [committing your transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions). BTW, EF already implements unit of work so that may be overkill. Also I would replace FirstOrDefault() with Single() - you want an exception if nothing is found. Also, not sure you need the Bind. Since you have a view model only those values are passed.

I would rewrite the body as:

```
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (DB)
        {
            foreach (var desc in DB.IncidentDescriptions.Where(d => d.AccidentHeaderId == supervisor.AccidentHeaderId)) 
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(desc.Id + " " + desc.Description);
            }
            DB.IncidentDescriptions.Remove(DB.IncidentDescriptions.Single(d => d.AccidentHeaderId == supervisor.AccidentHeaderId));
            DB.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Incident"); 
    }
    return View(supervisor);
}
```